# Facebook search for app redirect

Tags: facebook, search, redirect, iframe-app

I recently build an iframe app for within Facebook, and for facebook only. So no need to call the iframe outside of Facebook. The only problem i have now, is that as soon as i search for the app like this:
http://i44.tinypic.com/30rla83.png

I get the following warning: http://i43.tinypic.com/2uh1w20.png

I can't seem to find out how to configure the app so it won't redirect, but goes directly to the app itself. The only values set are the 'Website' and 'Page Tab' value. When i set a value for the 'App on Facebook', the iframe gets included in the game/app format (with Facebook games in the right bar) by Facebook, and not the Facebook page app content format.

And when i delete or adjust the 'Website' value and i use Facebook search, i get the error that the app is not configured correctly. It's now set to the full addresss outside of Facebook, because when i configure it to the Facebook App URL i get the same error.

The only value i'm sure of is the 'Page Tab' value.

Thanks in advance guys, i can't seem to find the answer myself..

**UPDATE: it turns out the 'you are being redirected'-page only occurs with my Facebook profile! Probably because I'm the Facebook Page admin or the app creator? Anyway, as far as I'm concerned; case closed and problem solved :)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's slightly confusing which options apply to what types of app on Facebook - and the behaviour of the search is slightly unintuitive but here are some pointers that might help you:

- If your app is going to only exist as a page tab, it doesn't really make sense to search for it (it could theoretically exist on multiple facebook pages). These won't show up in search results unless you have also set one of the following two options as well
- If you have set up your app as a canvas app, "app on facebook" in the developer settings then when you search for the App, it will redirect you to the canvas page (your iframe being pulled into a Facebook canvas.
- if you have set your app up to work with Facebook Connect "Log in to my website using Facebook." in the developer settings, and you haven't also set up your app to operate as a canvas app, then Facebook will assume that you have a web app that is external to Facebook, and searches will redirect the user to your website url.

So, what you probably need to do is either remove your website url from your facebook settings if you aren't using Facebook Connect (in which case your app won't show up in Search results) or create a canvas page as well, which redirects you to the correct facebook page tab.

Comment: Thanks for your very detailed answer. I do only want to the app to exist as a page tab, and it isn't set up as a canvas app. But as soon i clear the "Log in to my website using Facebook." field, i get the following error when i click the search result:
http://i40.tinypic.com/nbw6t2.png

It does however work when i go to the app through the Facebook page. You think that the search result is just cache and wil dissapear eventually? 
But what i don't understand is how other apps i granted permission to use my personal info do show up in search results, without them being canvas apps. any idea? ty

Comment: The reason is that (if you have installed the app by granting permission for it to access your data) they are Facebook Connect Apps i.e. they have a value set for "Log in to my website using Facebook." - otherwise you couldn't sign into them.

Comment: Alright i get that now, thanks. Let's say i would configure it as "Log in to my website using Facebook."-app, because i like the app to be found by searching. I would like to find out how to skip this this page: http://i43.tinypic.com/2uh1w20.png. I've seen it with other apps through search results; when i copy paste the https://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=xxxx url in my browser, it gives me the redirecting page (like the image above), but when i go there through the search result i get redirected right away... maybe a javascript trick or a setting after all?